# vba loop through textboxes then place values in a range of cells

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have another newbie scenario regarding loops and TextBox in UserForms.

Here is what i am trying to accomplish when the "Save" CommandButton is clicked.

1. A loop runs through each text box that name starts with "co" and ends in a number 1-15.
2. If there is a value in that text box the code adds that value to the first cell in a specified range then moves onto the next textbox and cell.

Below is an image of the worksheet with cell ranges and also the userform.

WS and UserForm
[image]

Am i on the right track with the code I have started? or is there a more efficient way to do this without a loop?  Thank you in advance for your assistance with this.

```
Private Sub SandCont_Click()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsJHA As Worksheet
    Dim wsRange1b As Range
    Dim wsRange1c As Range
    Dim wsRange2 As Range
    Dim wsRange3 As Range
    Dim wsRange4 As Range
    Dim wsRange5 As Range
    Dim wsRange6 As Range
    Dim wsRange7 As Range
    Dim wsRange8 As Range
    Dim wsRange9 As Range
    Dim wsRange10 As Range
    Dim c As Control
    Dim i As Integer    'used to loop through cells in ranges listed below???
    Dim x As String     'will be first two characters of textbox name
    Dim y As String     'will be last character of textbox name
    Dim z As Integer    'used to loop through textboxes on userform???

    Set wb = Application.ThisWorkbook
    Set wsJHA = wb.Sheets("JHA Keying")
    Set wsRange1b = wsJHA.Range("B4:B11")
    Set wsRange1c = wsJHA.Range("C4:C11")


    For Each c In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(c) = "TextBox" Then
            x = Left(c.Name, 2)
            y = Right(c.Name, 3)
            If x = "co" And y <= "015" Then
                wsRange1b.Value = c.Value
            End If
        End If
    Next c

'    Application.ThisWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: *y <= "015"*? What is it?

Comment: Moreover, in a loop you're always assigning values to the *same* range. Is it OK?

Comment: each text box ends with a number 001 through 1xx and i forgot to remove the " " around that value.

Comment: what im hoping to accomplish is the value of the textboxs' name that start with "co" and end in 1 through 15 will transfer the value to that first range of cells.  Forgive me if im not explaining it very well im still very new to VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the name of text box this way:

```
If c.Name Like "co*0[0-1][0-5]" Then...
```

#### Explanation:

- **co** - matches 'co' literally
- ***** - matches any number of any characters
- **0** - matches zero
- **[0-1]** - matches digit in a range from 0 to 1
- **[0-5]** - matches digit in a range from 0 to 5

Comment: that worked perfectly.  Would you mind explaining what the [0-1][0-5] means?

Comment: Thank you very much @JohnyL.  This was a great help and will be  very useful for the rest of this project i am working on.

Comment: @ZackE You're welcome! :) You could use regular expressions, of course, but Like can handle this case with a breeze.